# Value of Intel Pentium Processor

Tags: cpu

I have a CPU that reads:
`INTEL Ⓜ © '01
PENTIUM®4
2.40GHZ/512/533/1.525V
SL6DV MALAY
0248A225-0527`

I was wondering if it was worth anything?

Comment: Worth anything like how ? Money or usability on a PC ?

Comment: Both, it came out an old server. Is it worth keeping, selling or binning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU alone is probably worth more in metal than for its processing functions.

I've seen full computers with more recent CPUs that are sold for less than 50$ so the CPU alone is probably worth next to nothing.